# C2660: _splitpath_s fails with std::array error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 is a bit weird on language array that in global function it's allowed to initialize one as `char result[100] = { 0 };`, but not if it's a class's member -- referring to 
[Workaround for error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877757/workaround-for-error-c2536-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays-in-vi), for `int m_array[3];` inside `class A`, `A() :m_array{ 0, 1, 2 } {}` fails with Error C2536: "'A::A::m_array' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays".

In the same post [a work-around is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19890214/826203), using 
`std::array<int, 3> m_array;` instead and initilzie with 
`A() : m_array ({ 0, 1, 2 }) {}`
, IDE red underlined "0" hinting "*Error: braces cannot be omitted for this subobject initializer.*" but can compile.

Even better, [one comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877757/workaround-for-error-c2536-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays-in-vi#comment29863977_19890214)  suggested use an extra pair of braces
`A() : m_array ({ { 0, 1, 2 } }) {}` , and now all smooth!

To pass a `std::array` to a function requiring a `char *` parameter, [std::array over c style array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226276/stdarray-over-c-style-array) suggest use `my_array.data()` where `my_array` is a `std::array`.

Now I met a problem with `_spitpath_s`:

The traditional `char *` style compiles 
`_splitpath_s(fullpathfilename, drive, dir, name, ext)` where the parameters are all `char` arrays; but using `std::array` will trigger error C2660:

```
class B2
{
public:
    const int MAX_LEN = 200;
    std::array<char, 200> drive, dir, name, ext;
    B2() :drive({ { 0 } }), dir({ { 0 } }), name({ { 0 } }), ext({ { 0 } }) {}
    void split(const char * fullpathfilename)   {
        _splitpath_s(fullpathfilename, drive.data(), dir.data(), name.data(), ext.data()); //error C2660: '_splitpath_s' : function does not take 5 arguments
    }
};
```

.

Why `_splitpath_s` fails here? This is an old C style function, defined in `stdlib.h`, if there's a work-around in C++, also acceptable.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please only use the relevant tag (C++ in this case).

Comment: @kaylum `_splitpath_s` is a function in `stdlib.h` from old C days.

Comment: @athos: Doesn't matter - you're writing C++. `_splitpath_s` is actually a Windows API function anyway, not part of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5 parameter version of `_splitpath_s` is a template function, expecting a character pointer for the input path, and C-style character arrays for the other 4.  Since you are passing in C++ `array` objects, the template is not generated and, due to SFINAE it is not available so there is no function that takes 5 parameters.

To use it you'll have to use the 9 parameter version, where you pass in the input addresses and buffer sizes.

Comment: But `dir`, `name`, and `ext` also need `.data` on them, then (since that returns a `char *`) you'll need to pass in the lengths.

Comment: you are right, I can use the 9 parameter version. but one more question, how could C++ function delcaration differentiate `char array[200]` from `char *`? I thought during the call there's an automatic "decay" from `char` array to `char` pointer?

Comment: An array decays to a pointer when passed to a function, but in a template instantiation the compiler treats them differently.  In this case it uses the known compile time array size to fill in the appropriate value to then call the 9 parameter version.

Comment: @athos: It's actually because you pass by reference. You can do it without templates — `void foo(const char (&array)[42]) {} const char array[42] = {}; int main() { foo(array); }` will work just fine — it's just that, for general-purpose use, you'd need to manually write an overload for each combination of array dimensions that you want to use!